# Search engine that creates tables of information about a subject from unstructured data

Tags: database, data-analysis, search, knowledge-organization

I am looking for a webapp that would gather data from the web in a very similar way to a search engine, but instead of presenting the results as a list of titles and abstracts, it would dump the results into a table, attempting to extract metadata from the pages it had in its internal indexes.

*(Once upon a time Google had a web-app called Google Squared. Is there any other tool like that today? I remember this as being super useful, and amazingly intuitive - although not perfect, it was an awesome tool for non-programmers to quickly create rather complex queries and have rendered almost immediately with very little effort.)*

UPDATE:
Here is the demo of [Google Squared](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=__INtIXNLmI) from 13 years ago.

According to the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Squared) it was created in response to Wolfram-Alpha, but WA is limited in scope by design (or I don't know/have access to other features).

This is the pertinent description from the Wikipedia page:
Google Squared **extracted structured data** from across the web and **presented its results in spreadsheet-like format**. Each search query returned a table of search results which has its own set of columns - common attributes that are associated with the topic of a search.

Comment: Please edit the question to make it fully understandable to people who have no idea what Squared is. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Seems that you would like to write your own crawler + index.  
Another alternative is to use the search API of a search engine directly (e.g. [Google custom search](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/introduction)), and storing those attributes that you find interesting into a file or table.

Comment: Well... I'm looking for something with a layman's user interface. Something a kid could use without the need to learn how to interface with APIs and a programing language. In essence a 'data-toy' that can produce meaningful output.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a web crawler.

You have 2 options:

- **Search for an online web crawler:** you will find Google Squared [alternatives](https://www.webcrawler.com/).
- **Build you web crawler:** one choice could be [sparkler](https://github.com/USCDataScience/sparkler) but there are many more online.

Comment: In essence every proper search engine is already a crawler, and an indexer. But no, I'm not interested in a crawler. Maybe a suite where a crawler is attached to an indexer that automagically discovers the metadata. I think Squares was inspired by Wolfram Alpha. But that is limited in scope by design.

Comment: So I haven't understood your goal. In what Wolfram Alpha is limited? Because you cannot do a plain text question? Because you cannot generate an output? Give an example of a search you would like to do and what you expect to receive.